# creating a subclass in java

Tags: java, class, subclass, super

I need to create a subclass that creates a method to calculate the value of the inventory of a product. The subclass method should also add a 5% restocking fee to the value of the inventory of that product.  It should also modify the output to display the additional feature you chose and the restocking fee. This is what I have so far. Need help getting info from subclass tools to class Product. Here's my main:

```
// This is an inventory program part 1 "Section 2", Section 1 is at bottom with "//".
// begin main class
public class inventory {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // create array
        Product[] productsobject = new Product[2];

        // initialize array
        productsobject[0]= new Product(5211, "hammer", 1585, 7.48);
        productsobject[1]= new Product(5212, "shovel", 900, 9.48);

        float entireValue;// method to calculate entire inventory
        {
        entireValue = (productsobject[0].getItemTotalValue() + productsobject[1].getItemTotalValue());
        }

        // output products information one at a time
        productsobject[0].printInfo();
        productsobject[1].printInfo();

        //output entire inventory amount
        System.out.println("The entire value of both products is $" + entireValue + ".");
    }
}
```

Here's my `Product` class:

```
//Begin class Product
    public class Product extends tools{

        //declare data types
        Integer productID;
        String productName;
        Integer quantity;
        Double productPrice;
        float itemTotalValue;
        //end of declaring data types

        //Constructor
        public Product (Integer productID, String productName, Integer quantity, Double productPrice)
        {
            super();
             this.productID= productID;
             this.productName= productName;
             this.quantity = quantity;
             this.productPrice= productPrice;
             // end of Constructor
         }
         //the following is getters and setters
        public Integer getProductID() {
            return productID;
        }

        public void setProductID(Integer productID) {
            this.productID = productID;
        }

        public String getProductName() {
            return productName;
        }

        public void setProductName(String productName) {
            this.productName = productName;
        }

        public Integer getQuantity() {
            return quantity;
        }

        public void setQuantity(Integer quantity) {
            this.quantity = quantity;
        }

        public Double getProductPrice() {
            return productPrice;
        }

        public void setProductPrice(Double productPrice) {
            this.productPrice = productPrice;
        }


        // end of getters and setters

        public void printInfo(){// method for sorting array items
          System.out.println("This item is a " + getProductName() + ". The item # is " + getProductID() + ". The number of items available are " + getQuantity() + " and the price per item is $" + getProductPrice() + ". The total value of this item is $" + getItemTotalValue() + "."); 
       }

}
//end class Product
```

Here's my subclass `tools`:

```
public class tools {

    String typeFinish;

    public tools(String typeFinish)
    {
        this.typeFinish= typeFinish;
    }

    public String getTypeFinish() {
        return typeFinish;
    }

    public void setTypeFinish(String typeFinish) {

        super();
        this.typeFinish = typeFinish;
    }

    public float getItemTotalValue() {
        itemTotalValue = (float) ((productPrice * quantity) * 0.05);
        return itemTotalValue;
    }

    public void setItemTotalValue(float itemTotalValue) {
        this.itemTotalValue = itemTotalValue;
    }

    void typeFinish(){
        System.out.print("This tool has a fiberglass finish and the restocking fee is 5%.");

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to find out which is the parent class and which is the child class. The child class will always extends the parent class, so if Product extends tools, then tools is your parent class here. (By the way, please capitalize the first letter of class names, i.e. Tools)

I'm also not quite sure which part of the data you are unable to get. You can already use the public getters and setters you have written.

Please clarify your issue.

Comment: I think you have to first look at inheritance and class hierarchy. Here read this - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/inheritance.html

Comment: Im trying to get my class Product to recognize my information in the subclass tools such as the output statement in typeFinish.

Comment: Im trying to get my Product class to recognize itemTotalValue in my subclass tools and I am trying to print  the typeFinish() statement too